# llbl stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, llblgenpro, llblgen

I have a problem on llbl. I have a stored procedure in my sql database and I want to get the stored procedure code in code(C#) side with llbl.

Sql Code:

```
SELECT    ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Routines
WHERE     ROUTINE_Name = 'FillStatistics'
```

This query is getting stored procedure code but I have to do this with llbl.

How can I do this?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest starting with the Online Docs for LLBL.  In reference to your particular request i would start here.  http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/3.0/Linq%20to%20Sql/hh_start.htm

Answer (score 1):

Add a call to the stored procedure in the designer, and then generating code which will contain a method to call the proc. See: http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/3.0/Designer/hh_goto.htm#How%20To/AddEditStoredProcedureCall.htm